# What is the css solution to this padding problem?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
<div id="action-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="selected">selected</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">selected</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the styles:

```
#action-nav
{
    text-align:center;


}

#action-nav ul li
{

    height: 48px;
    width: 112px;
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;

}

#action-nav ul li a
{
   text-decoration:none;
   padding-top :15px;
   height: 48px;
   width: 112px;
   display: block;
}

#action-nav ul li:hover a
{
     color:#fff;

}

#action-nav ul li:hover, #action-nav ul li a.selected
{

    background-image: url('../Images/link_red_bg.jpg');
    color:#fff;


}
```

the a.selected class is the issue.  It should look like it does in the adjacent li:hover style.  What did I miss?

Comment: Could you put something on http://jsfiddle.net for us?

Comment: they look the same to me. what's exactly the difference?

Comment: what are you trying to do? you're just giving code with no explanation on what you're trying to do with the code. be more specific... and jsfiddle is always helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be repeating, in which case,

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subtract the padding from the height.

Answer (score 0):

use line-height instead of height

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the "selected" class to the parent <li>.

Additionally, specifying the exact width and height of the child <a> is redundant; simply change both values to 100% so they automatically match the dimensions of the parent <li>.